# How to convert a path in python?

Tags: python

How to convert a path:

```
t = 'c:\temp\xx'
```

I want to get "something like" that:

```
x = r't'
```

I usually uses
    x = r'c:\temp\xx'
and receives
x = r'c:\\temp\\xx'

I don't know how to assign the 'r' to another object..

Comment: Err, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no clear transformation from `'c:\temp\xx'` to `r't'`.  What is this "conversion" you speak of?

Comment: So you want to convert a string to a raw string? The problem is, once it's evaluated as `t`, you lose that data. You don't know whether a `\temp` was entered as `\temp` or `       emp`. (it's not keeping my whitespace, but imagine a tabs-length space before "emp")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can apply `r` string prefix to string literals. So you need:

```
x = r'c:\temp\xx'
```

The `r't'` expression will give you a raw `'t'` string. That's it.

If what you need is to duplicate the `\` character on your destination string `x`, you can use replace:

```
x = t.encode('string_escape')
```